# How to execute code *after* async function has finished and returned to caller's context?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have an async function and I want to execute some task **after** the function has returned to the original context.

Here's a sample:

```swift
actor MyActor {
   func doTask() await -> Int {

     let result = await operation()
     Task {
       print("2. All tasks done!")
     }
     return result
   }
}

let actor = MyActor()
let taskResult = await actor.doTask()
print("1. Task done")
```

I want output always to be

> 1. Task done
> 2. All tasks done!

However, sometimes the output is reversed.
I suppose this is because Swift might be switching threads when returning to the original caller.
Is there any way to actually wait for it so that "2. All tasks done" is called last?

Comment: What is special about the call `print("1. Task done")`? Why should anything inside `doTask` know about it and wait until it returns? That's rather unreasonable isn't it? I feel this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: In my case, "All tasks done" would be called when all tasks scheduled on the actor have finished.
But I want to give callers the chance to do some work after this particular task have finished - because in my app, I terminate the process when all tasks have finished.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to execute some task after the function has returned to the original context.

There's no magic here. If you want a task to execute at a certain point, then you need to start it at that point, not before.

What you are asking for is almost literally the same as

> How do I make the `print("2 ...")` appear after the `print("1 ...")` in the following.

```
struct MyStruct {
   func doTask() -> Int {

     let result = operation()
     print("2. All tasks done!")
  
     return result
   }
}

let actor = MyStruct()
let taskResult = actor.doTask()
print("1. Task done")
```

In your case, the only way to ensure the `print("2 ...")` appears after the `print("1 ...")` is to start the asynchronous task after you have done the `print("1 ...")`.

You'll need to split the actor function in two.

```
actor MyActor {
   func doOperation() async -> Int {

     let result = await operation()
     return result
   }
   func doTask(_ result: Int) async {

     Task {
       print("2. All tasks done!")
       // Use result in some way if you need to
     }
   }

}

let actor = MyActor()
let taskResult = await actor.doOperation()
print("1. Task done")
await actor.doTask(taskResult)
```